# How to transfer monetdb database to another machine

Tags: monetdb

I created monetdb database using the python library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-monetdb/11.16.0.7 on my ubuntu 12.04 lts server. Now I want to transfer this database to another ubuntu 12.04 lts server. However, I am unable to understand as to where(directory name) does monetdb create its database (within ubuntu 12.04) and what is the procedure which I must follow to transfer this database to another machine (so that i may query the database on another machine)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out where MonetDB stores data by running the following query in a client:

```
select value from environment() where name = 'gdk_dbfarm';
```

. Every database is a subdirectory of this directory. If you copy this directory to the same location on the other machine (and set permissions appropriately), you should get a replica of your database. Make sure you shut down the MonetDB server before copying.